# Only update when value is not null mySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I am working on an update query where the values should only update when the value is not null or empty. Now it updates everything regardless the value. Please help me out with this one.

```
$query = "UPDATE bundels 
SET batchkosten = CASE WHEN  ". $_POST['batchkosten'] . " IS NOT NULL
                   THEN  ". $_POST['batchkosten'] . "
                   ELSE batchkosten
              END CASE,
              CASE WHEN   ". $_POST['maandelijkse_kosten'] . "  IS NOT NULL
                   THEN   ". $_POST['maandelijkse_kosten'] . " 
                   ELSE maandelijkse_kosten
              END CASE,
              CASE WHEN   ". $_POST['aanmeldkosten'] . "  IS NOT NULL
                   THEN   ". $_POST['aanmeldkosten'] . " 
                   ELSE aanmeldkosten
              END CASE,
              CASE WHEN   ". $_POST['transactiekosten'] . "  IS NOT NULL
                   THEN   ". $_POST['transactiekosten'] . " 
                   ELSE transactiekosten
              END CASE,
              CASE WHEN   ". $_POST['referral'] . "  IS NOT NULL
                   THEN   ". $_POST['referral'] . " 
                   ELSE referral
              END CASE,
              CASE WHEN   ". $_POST['actief'] . "  IS NOT NULL
                   THEN   ". $_POST['actief'] . " 
                   ELSE actief
              END CASE
              WHERE bundel_id = ". $_POST['bundel_id'] . "";
        $result = mysql_query($query, $db) or die ('FOUT: werkt niet'); 
            header ("Location: vergelijker_bewerken.php");
        } else {
            $bundels = mysql_query("SELECT bundels.psp_id, psp.psp_id, psp_naam, bundels.bundel_id, batchkosten, maandelijkse_kosten, aanmeldkosten, transactiekosten, referral, actief from bundels
                                    JOIN psp
                                ON psp.psp_id = bundels.psp_ID"); 
}
```

Comment: Which value you are referring?

Comment: 1. Stop using the `mysql_` functions. They're deprecated and have been for years. They're also unsupported, and aren't getting any security updates. 2. Your code is very open to SQL injection. Use `PDO` or `MySQLi` with prepared statements and bind your variables. It wouldn't be hard to change `$_POST['bundel_id']` to `'' OR 1 = 1` to change all the records in the database. Bound variables would fix this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. Use *Prepared Statements* to escape user input and avoid SQL syntax errors and SQL injections.
2. You can use a `case`

   ```
   UPDATE bundels 
   SET batchkosten = case when ? is not null and length(?) > 0
                          then ?
                          else batchkosten
                     end,
   ...
   ```

Your current query translates to (which should throw an error actually)

```
UPDATE bundels 
SET batchkosten = CASE WHEN ? length(?) > 0 
                       THEN ?
                       ELSE batchkosten 
                  END 
WHERE bundel_id = ?
```

But use instead:

```
SET batchkosten = CASE WHEN ? is not null and length(?) > 0
```

Comment: I now have this:

$query = "UPDATE bundels 
 SET batchkosten = CASE WHEN  ". $_POST['batchkosten'] . " IS NOT NULL
                       THEN  ". $_POST['batchkosten'] . "
                       ELSE batchkosten
                  END,
      CASE WHEN   ". $_POST['maandelijkse_kosten'] . "  IS NOT NULL
                       THEN   ". $_POST['maandelijkse_kosten'] . " 
                       ELSE maandelijkse_kosten
                  END, etc..

yet it doesn't work and I can't find the solution. Can you please help me with this one?

Comment: it doesn't update

// moment i'll put the complete code in the first post

Comment: Your input probably is not null, but an empty string. Use `length()` for instance to check that. And as mentioned in the answer - use Prepared Statements. You will run into trouble sooner as you think if not.

Comment: I tried using the length() part in the understanding I'll have to put it like length(".$_POST['batchkosten'].") yet it still doesn't update. this is my code, it's probably something very easy..

 $query = "UPDATE bundels 
 SET batchkosten = CASE WHEN  ". $_POST['batchkosten'] . " length('".$_POST['batchkosten']."') > 0
                       THEN  ". $_POST['batchkosten'] . "
                       ELSE batchkosten
     END
      WHERE bundel_id = ". $_POST['bundel_id'] . "";

Answer (score 1):

you can write script some like this maybe:

```
$query = "Update bundels SET ";
$columns = array( "batchkosten", 
                  "maandelijkse_kosten", 
                  "aanmeldkosten",    
                  "transactiekosten", 
                  "referral", 
                  "actief");

foreach($columns as $column){
    if(isset($_POST[$column]) && !empty($_POST[$column])){
        $query .= $column . " = " $_POST[$column] . " ";            
    }
}

$query .= " WHERE bundel_id = " . $_POST['bundel_id'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the query to this

```
$query= "UPDATE bundels SET
batchkosten =                ' ". $_POST['batchkosten'] . " ',
maandelijkse_kosten =        ' ". $_POST['maandelijkse_kosten'] . " ',
aanmeldkosten =              ' ". $_POST['aanmeldkosten'] . " ',
transactiekosten =           ' ". $_POST['transactiekosten'] . " ',
referral =                   ' ". $_POST['referral'] . " ',
actief =                     ' ". $_POST['actief'] . " '
WHERE bundel_id = ". $_POST['bundel_id'] . " ".
"and your_attribut is not null and your_attribut != ''";
```

Don't forget to change "your_attribut".