# ReactJS MySQL update if value is not null/empty

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I'm a beginner in react js and I'm trying to update password and image fields only if they are not empty values coming from the frontend based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27484388/2121311) but I'm getting the following error:

> Error: Incorrect arguments to mysqld_stmt_execute

node.js script:

```
async updateUser(req, res) {

        const { id } = req.params;

        const {
            fullname,
            CPF,
            RG,
            born,
            email,
            phone,
            password,
            level, 
            city, 
            cityHallState } = req.body;

        let image;
        if (req.files.length > 0) {
            image = req.files[0].filename;
        } else {
            image = '';
        }

        let created = new Date();

        let date = ("0" + created.getDate()).slice(-2);
        let month = ("0" + (created.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2);
        let year = created.getFullYear();
        let hours = created.getHours();
        let minutes = created.getMinutes();
        let seconds = created.getSeconds();

        let updatedAt = year + "-" + month + "-" + date + " " + hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds;

        try {

            await conn.execute('UPDATE register SET fullname = ?, CPF = ?, RG = ?, born = ?, email = ?, phone = ?, city = ?, state = ?, password = CASE WHEN ? IS NOT NULL AND LENGTH(?) > 0 THEN ? ELSE password END, image = CASE WHEN ? IS NOT NULL AND LENGTH(?) > 0 THEN ? ELSE image END, level = ?, updated = ? WHERE id = ?',
                [fullname, CPF, RG, born, email, phone, city, cityHallState, password, image, level, updatedAt, id],
                function (err, results, fields) {

                    console.log('register errors: ' + err);
                    console.log(results);

                    if (err == null) {
                        if (results.affectedRows > 0) {
                            return res.json('user updated');
                        } else {
                            return res.json('could not update user data');
                        }
                    } else {
                        return res.json('error updating user data: ' + err);
                    }
                });
        } catch (error) {
            return res.json('could not update user data. catch error: ' + error);
        }
}
```

If I remove password and image fields the query executes fine. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to set the defaults to the string `'password'` or `'image'` if the lengths are greater than 0? If so, you will probably need single quotes around those:

```
UPDATE register
SET fullname = ?,
    CPF = ?,
    RG = ?,
    born = ?,
    email = ?,
    phone = ?,
    city = ?,
    state = ?,
    password = CASE WHEN ? IS NOT NULL AND LENGTH(?) > 0 THEN ? ELSE 'password' END,
    image = CASE WHEN ? IS NOT NULL AND LENGTH(?) > 0 THEN ? ELSE 'image' END,
    level = ?,
    updated = ?
WHERE id = ?'
```

You can also clean up the query by removing the case statements altogether and setting a default for both `password` and `image` in javascript:

```js
async updateUser(req, res) {

        const { id } = req.params;

        const {
            fullname,
            CPF,
            RG,
            born,
            email,
            phone,
            password = 'password',
            level, 
            city, 
            cityHallState } = req.body;

        let image = 'image';
        if (req.files.length > 0) {
          image = req.files[0].filename;
        }

        ...

        try {

          await conn.execute('UPDATE register SET fullname = ?, CPF = ?, RG = ?, born = ?, email = ?, phone = ?, city = ?, state = ?, password = ?, image = ?, level = ?, updated = ? WHERE id = ?'
        ...
```

Comment: No. I'd like to fields to be updated only if they are not blank/empty from the input form. User would have the choice to fill them or not. If not filled, it must not change the original value in database.